# Multiprocess Synchronization with a Single Semaphore

Tags: semaphore

We're covering multithreaded programming in a class I'm taking. The professor offered a bonus question that I have been trying, to no avail, to figure out:

Each of processes P0, P1, P2 and P3 have to wait for the other three to cross or reach a particular synchronization point in their code, and only then may that process cross its own synchronization point.

I already know how to answer the question with four semaphores, the hard part is doing it with only one semaphore.

Any suggestions or hints as to how to proceed?

Comment: Your wording of the problem is kind of imprecise, so you're unlikely to get good guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize your semaphore at -4 if it's not a binary one.

Comment: I didn't down vote you but I suspect it was because you can't initialize semaphores with negative values.  In POSIX the value is unsigned and the Windows docs specifically state a value of 0 or greater.

Comment: this is quite limitative: i often need an inverse semaphore and i could never find one. while not possible due to software limitations, his answer is perfectly logical. a bit of explanation would have been welcome though.

Comment: It's a useful construct and if you search around you can find various implementations but I get the feeling there is no consensus on what the exact semantics should be.

Comment: That's the solution I came up with... but as the other commenters (and my professor) have pointed out it's not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You are a little light on the constraints imposed on your solution but see [The Little Book of Semaphores](http://www.greenteapress.com/semaphores/) and read through the sections on barriers.  That should give you some ideas.

Comment: Thank you for the resource, that should be quite helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the professor had meant to say that you could use two semaphores instead of one. He believes, as I do after having thought about the problem for a while, that it is impossible to do with a single semaphore.

Comment: That's why I commented on your not mentioning much about constraints.  You can do it with one semaphore and mutex protecting a counter but I wasn't sure if you could use mutexes or if they would count as a second semaphore.